# Binding to an object's property doesn't update when the object is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have several bindings to an object representing a product. However, whenever I update the underlying product object, none of my bindings update. I suspect that this is happening because Angular is still watching the old object's properties. How can I get Angular to behave as I expect?

Template

```
<div>
    <span>{{ selectedProduct.name }}</span>
    <ul>
        <li 
            ng-click="selectedProduct = product;"
            ng-repeat="product in products"
        ><img src="{{product.imgUrl}}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Directive

```
module.directive('productList', function () {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
        products: '=',
        selectedProduct: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.selectedProduct = products[0];
    }
});
```

EDIT to clarify usage
My directive is consumed like so

TEMPLATE

```
<div ng-controller="arbitraryController">
    <product-list products="products" selected-product="selectedProduct"></product-list>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
module.controller('arbitraryController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{
        name:'boots', 
        imgUrl:'boots.jpg'
    },{
        name:'fluffy bunnies', 
        imgUrl:'bunnies.jpg'
    }];
});
```

Comment: Please add the code where you update the product list, it's impossible to tell by just looking at the directive.

Comment: where is `productList` usage?

Comment: and in the directive controller,products comes out of thin air... please write the correct code.

Comment: Hopefully the usage code would make it more clear. The idea is that `selectedProducts` would be a property that other directives can use (e.g. a <product-details> directive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One think to remember, when passing objects among scopes is:

> "Whenever you have ng-model there's gotta be a dot in there somewhere. If you don't have a dot, you're doing it wrong."

The cite comes from this video [angular JS - best practice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) (29:19), and is nicely explained here:

- [Nested Scopes in Angular JS](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html)

I creted a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3HPpTj?p=preview), showing how to do that. We will put all related stuff into one model instance called `model`:

```
.controller('arbitraryController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      var products = [
        {name: 'boots', imgUrl: 'boots.jpg'},
        {name: 'fluffy bunnies', imgUrl: 'bunnies.jpg'}
      ];

      $scope.model = {
        products : products,
        selectedProduct : products[0],
      };
    }
  ])
```

And pass it to directive: `<product-list product-model="model"></product-list>`, which code will be updated to:

```
.directive('productList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      templateUrl: 'products.tpl.html',
      scope: {
        model: '=productModel',
      },
    }
})
```

How it works together observe [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3HPpTj?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't using ng-model, but... the suggestion about the 'dot' did point me in the right direction. The issue was that I was trying to update something 'before the dot'. Above I was passing around 'selectedProduct', and binding it's properties, which was fine. My issue came when a user selected a Product, and I needed to change what 'selectedProduct' referenced. That was the 'before the dot' reference that I didn't realize. Refactoring it so that 'Product' became a property of a 'selected' object cleared up the whole problem!